# Unable to find Printers after deployment

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, printing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an internal application for our organization where we have default Windows authentication for all applications.

My requirement is to display all installed printers in the local machine. I am using [WebClientPrint for ASP.NET](http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-Zebra-ZPL-commands-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-the-client-printer/) to load printers.

I have installed the `wcpp-2.0.15.918-win.exe`, in my local machine and server.
While i am testing the application in localhost its working fine and loading printer names.
But after deploying the application on server, it is not loading the printer names! I also tried with these given settings from [WebClientPrint with ASP.NET Authentication enabled](http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-use-WebClientPrint-with-ASP-NET-Authentication-enabled/) but failed.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5, C#, Windows authentication.

Comment: Are the printers in question installed on the server?

Comment: yes. i have few local and one network printer installed on server

Comment: but webclientprint is intended to load printers from local machine not from server right